# node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node missing when using clasp on linux

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, add-on, gmail-addons, clasp

I'm using [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) to build an add-on gmail.

I created a empty folder and run this command:

> clasp login

I have an error like this

> Error: The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
>   Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/@google/clasp/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775815/node-v57-linux-x64-grpc-node-node-missing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but it is not a solution for me.

How can i fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs Error - Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system Expected directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758008/nodejs-error-failed-to-load-grpc-binary-module-because-it-was-not-installed-fo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue today and it seems I've found a workaround:
The following commands seem to fix the issue:

```
    cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grpcc/node_modules/grpc/src
    sudo npm --unsafe-perm install
```

Though the installation process finished with errors, the missing file was there and the grpcc was working.

Comment: yes, I've just found a solution from https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/188, then i ran `sudo npm i @google/clasp -g --unsafe-perm`, it worked.